# How do I list all blocks with PHP enabled inside?

Tags: 7, blocks

I added a custom block that uses PHP, and now I get the following notice message:

> Trying to get property of non-object in eval() (line 5 of /public_html/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).

I am trying to find which one is causing that notice, and since I have many blocks, I would rather do it without using the user interface.

Is there a way to get a list of blocks using PHP? I would be happy also with a solution using the Views module, as long as I don't need to look at the settings of each block, one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find all custom blocks that have PHP code as their input format, you can query the `block_custom` table. The `format` column will contain the key `php_code`.

```
$blocks = db_select('block_custom')
  ->fields('block_custom')
  ->condition('format', 'php_code')
  ->execute();
foreach($blocks as $block) {
  // @TODO: Add your own actionable code
}
```